# Error : can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python-3.x

please help I can't fix this one I'm stuck here for 2 hours ago I can't pass this
when I input only one username it's ok but if I input more then one username it's an error like the title

[image]

[image]

I want output like this

[image]

Comment: Instead of screenshots or links to screenshots, please paste your code and format it using code markup ({} button) .  Thank you!

Comment: If you read the traceback it tells you exactly where the error occurs: line 24, because on the first iteration you increment cnt by `len(name)` then on line 25 you convert `cnt` to a string, on the next iteration when you hit line 24 again it's a string, and incrementing it blows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are replacing your counter (cnt) with a string:

cnt = str(cnt)

Use a different variable name for the string variable, such as:

cnt_str = str(cnt)